# Flutter: Google Sign In - Can't login

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having yet another problem with the google_sign_in plugin for Flutter. The plugin is installed correctly and Flutter is up to date. My app is also registered for google sign in. The problem that I'm having is that the typical google signin window pops up with my accounts to choose from, but when I press on one of my accounts the terminal throws an exception:

```
E/Surface ( 3522): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40d5db0
E/flutter ( 3522): [ERROR:../../lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] 
Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 3522): PlatformException(canceled, 0, null)
E/flutter ( 3522): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
(package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:518:7)
E/flutter ( 3522): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
(package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:140:18)
E/flutter ( 3522): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3522): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod 
(package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:131:52)
E/flutter ( 3522): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3522): #3      GoogleSignIn.signIn 
(package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:145:43)
```

I'm using this code to login when a button is pressed:

```
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Sign up", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, color: Colors.white)),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            onPressed: () async {
              await googleSignIn.signIn();
              print("UID: " + googleSignIn.currentUser.id);
              print("Email: " + googleSignIn.currentUser.email);
              print("Display name: " + googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName);
            }
          )
```

I am working on Android devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates a problem with the code signing of your app not matching what's on the server. Check to make sure you've uploaded the correct signing key hash and package name to the console. Also check to make sure your google-services.json matched as well.

Comment: I created a second project and did it all over again and it worked. Sorry, posted this question a bit to quick.